# Qual è il significato di "appiattire" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel libro *Prima lezione di storia della lingua italiana*, di Luca Serianni, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Nella bella introduzione che Ghinassi scrisse per una ristampa della *Storia* (1988) – bella appunto perché nient’affatto celebrativa e oleografica – emergevano due riserve, due prese di distanza. La prima è legata alla ricostruzione storica “a una sola arcata”, «dai placiti cassinesi o da Dante ai tempi nostri, secondo uno schema prospettico che **appiattisce** sul presente un passato secolare, poggiando magari sul presupposto, pure miglioriniano, che la nazione e la coscienza nazionale italiana sia nata già, miracolosamente compiuta, al tempo di Dante, anzi sia stata creata da Dante stesso».

Sul [vocabolario Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/appiattire) ho visto che il verbo "appiattire" ha l'accezione seguente:

> In senso fig., ridurre a un livello più basso: *a. le retribuzioni*; anche avvilire, togliere vivacità e originalità: *la monotonia appiattisce la vita*

Tuttavia, non riesco a capire il significato di questo termine nel brano sopra citato. Forse qualcosa come "rendere banale" o "dare una visione superficiale"?

Comment: Mi sembra che la tua interpretazione sia corretta e aggiungerei, visto che ne sai di matematica, che io ci vedo proprio, dal punto di vista figurato, qualcosa come una “proiezione” da un certo spazio a un sottospazio di dimensione inferiore.

Comment: @DaG:  Mmmm... Come se dal "passato secolare" (lo "spazio") si percepisse soltanto questa "proiezione sul sottospazio di dimensione inferiore"? Può darsi.

Answer (score 2):

Direi che l'interpretazione che hai dato sia giusta.

"appiattire" è sinonimo di "schiacciare", e qui è inteso come ridurre la complessità di una lunga storia, fatta di numerosi eventi e sfaccettature, ad una semplice sentenza che la "schiaccia" in poche parole, che però celano molto altro.

Comment: concordo! La chiave per comprendere il significato, secondo me, sta nel riferimento alla prospettiva (schema prospettico). Pensa all'ombra di un oggetto, che la prospettiva 'appiattisce' al suolo.